# Tensorflow reuse variables different before and after training

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

In trying to learn a bit about Tensorflow, I had been building a Variational Auto Encoder, which is working, however I noticed that, after training, I was getting different results from the decoders which are sharing the same variables.

I created two decoders, because the first I train against my dataset, the second I want to eventually feed a new Z encoding in order to produce new values.

My check is that I shoud be able to send the Z values generated from the encoding process to both decoders and get equal results.

I have 2 Decoders (D, D_new).  D_new shares the variable scope from D.

before training, I can send values into the Encoder (E) to generate output values as well as the Z values it generated (Z_gen).

if I use Z_gen as input to D_new before training then its output is identical to the output of D, which is expected.

After a few iterations of training, however, the output of D compared with D_new begins to diverge (although they are quite similar).

I have paired this down to a more simple version of my code which still reproduces the error.  I'm wondering if others have found this to be the case and where I might be able to correct for it.

The below code can be run in a jupyter notebook.  I'm using Tensorflow r0.11 and Python 3.5.0

```
    import numpy as np
    import tensorflow as tf
    import matplotlib
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import os
    import pylab as pl
    mgc = get_ipython().magic
    mgc(u'matplotlib inline')
    pl.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = (8.0, 5.0)
```

```
    ##-- Helper function Just for visualizing the data
    def plot_values(values, file=None):
        t = np.linspace(1.0,len(values[0]),len(values[0]))
        for i in range(len(values)):
            plt.plot(t,values[i])
        if file is None:
            plt.show()
        else:
            plt.savefig(file)
        plt.close()
```

```
    def encoder(input, n_hidden, n_z):
        with tf.variable_scope("ENCODER"):
            with tf.name_scope("Hidden"):
                n_layer_inputs = input.get_shape()[1].value
                n_layer_outputs = n_hidden
                with tf.name_scope("Weights"):
                    w = tf.get_variable(name="E_Hidden", shape=[n_layer_inputs, n_layer_outputs], dtype=tf.float32)
                with tf.name_scope("Activation"):
                    a = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(input,w))
                prevLayer = a

            with tf.name_scope("Z"):
                n_layer_inputs = prevLayer.get_shape()[1].value
                n_layer_outputs = n_z
                with tf.name_scope("Weights"):
                    w = tf.get_variable(name="E_Z", shape=[n_layer_inputs, n_layer_outputs], dtype=tf.float32)
                with tf.name_scope("Activation"):
                    Z_gen = tf.matmul(prevLayer,w)
        return Z_gen

    def decoder(input, n_hidden, n_outputs, reuse=False):
        with tf.variable_scope("DECODER", reuse=reuse):
            with tf.name_scope("Hidden"):
                n_layer_inputs = input.get_shape()[1].value
                n_layer_outputs = n_hidden
                with tf.name_scope("Weights"):
                    w = tf.get_variable(name="D_Hidden", shape=[n_layer_inputs, n_layer_outputs], dtype=tf.float32)
                with tf.name_scope("Activation"):
                    a = tf.tanh(tf.matmul(input,w))
                prevLayer = a

            with tf.name_scope("OUTPUT"):
                n_layer_inputs = prevLayer.get_shape()[1].value
                n_layer_outputs = n_outputs
                with tf.name_scope("Weights"):
                    w = tf.get_variable(name="D_Output", shape=[n_layer_inputs, n_layer_outputs], dtype=tf.float32)
                with tf.name_scope("Activation"):
                    out = tf.sigmoid(tf.matmul(prevLayer,w))
        return out
```

Here is where the Tensorflow graph is setup:

```
    batch_size = 3
    n_inputs = 100
    n_hidden_nodes = 12
    n_z = 2

    with tf.variable_scope("INPUT_VARS"):
        with tf.name_scope("X"):
            X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_inputs))
        with tf.name_scope("Z"):
            Z = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, n_z))

    Z_gen = encoder(X,n_hidden_nodes,n_z)

    D = decoder(Z_gen, n_hidden_nodes, n_inputs)
    D_new = decoder(Z, n_hidden_nodes, n_inputs, reuse=True)

    with tf.name_scope("COST"):
        loss = -tf.reduce_mean(X * tf.log(1e-6 + D) + (1-X) * tf.log(1e-6 + 1 - D))
        train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.001, beta1=0.5).minimize(loss)
```

I'm generating a training set of 3 samples of normal distribution noise with 100 data points and then sort it to more easily visualize:

```
    train_data = (np.random.normal(0,1,(batch_size,n_inputs)) + 3) / 6.0
    train_data.sort()
    plot_values(train_data)
```

[image]

startup the session:

```
    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    sess.run(tf.group(tf.initialize_all_variables(), tf.initialize_local_variables()))
```

Lets just look at what the network initially generates before training...

```
    resultA, Z_vals = sess.run([D, Z_gen], feed_dict={X:train_data})
    plot_values(resultA)
```

[image]

Pulling the Z generated values and feeding them to D_new which is reusing the variables from D:

```
    resultB = sess.run(D_new, feed_dict={Z:Z_vals})
    plot_values(resultB)
```

[image]

Just for sanity I'll plot the difference between the two to be sure they're the same...
[image]

Now run 1000 training epochs and plot the result...

```
    for i in range(1000):
        _, resultA, Z_vals = sess.run([train_step, D, Z_gen], feed_dict={X:train_data})
    plot_values(resultA)
```

[image]

Now lets feed those same Z values to D_new and plot those results...

```
    resultB = sess.run(D_new, feed_dict={Z:Z_vals})
    plot_values(resultB)
```

[image]

They look pretty similar.  But (I think) they should be exactly the same.  Let's look at the difference...

```
    plot_values(resultA - resultB)
```

[image]

You can see there is some variation now.  This becomes much more dramatic with a larger network on more complex data, but still shows up in this simple example.
Any clues as to what's going on?

Comment: I'm not sure that this is an actual answer, because I still see these results in my more complex example.  But I find that if I sample the Z_gen values again, after the training loop, then the results from D and D_new match.  When I try this with more complex data (a training set of sine waves)  I still see some variation.  It seems like there is some very minor change in values once the run() method completes.

Answer (score 0):

There are some methods (don't know which one specifically) which can be supplied with a seed value. Besides those, I'm not even sure if the training process is completely deterministic, especially when the [GPU is involved](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2732), simply by the nature of parallelization.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36984291/tensorflow-not-being-deterministic-where-it-should).

Answer (score 0):

While I don't have a full explanation for the reason why, I was able to resolve my issue by changing:

```
for i in range(1000):
    _, resultA, Z_vals = sess.run([train_step, D, Z_gen], feed_dict={X:train_data})
plot_values(resultA)

resultB = sess.run(D_new, feed_dict={Z:Z_vals})
plot_values(resultB)
plot_values(resultA - resultB)
```

to...

```
for i in range(1000):
    _, resultA, Z_vals = sess.run([train_step, D, Z_gen], feed_dict={X:train_data})

resultA, Z_vals = sess.run([D, Z_gen], feed_dict={X:train_data})

plot_values(resultA)

resultB = sess.run(D_new, feed_dict={Z:Z_vals})
plot_values(resultB)
plot_values(resultA - resultB)
```

Note, that I simply ran and extracted the result and Z_vals one last time, without the `train_step`.

The reason I was still seeing problems in my more complex setup was that I had bias variables (even though they were set to 0.0) that were being generated with...

```
b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(self.bias_k, shape=[n_layer_outputs], dtype=tf.float32))
```

And that is somehow not considered while using `reuse` with a `tf.variable_scope`.  So there were variables technically not being reused.  Why they presented such a problem when set to 0.0 I'm not sure.