# DropoutWrapper being non-deterministic across runs?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In the beginning of my code, (outside the scope of a `Session`), I've set my random seed -

```
np.random.seed(1)
tf.set_random_seed(1)
```

This is what my dropout definition looks like -

```
cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=args.keep_prob, seed=1)
```

In my first experiment, I kept `keep_prob=1`. All results obtained were deterministic. I'm running this on a multicore CPU.

In my second experiment, I set `keep_prob=0.8` and I ran the same code two times. Each code had these statements,

```
sess.run(model.cost, feed)
sess.run(model.cost, feed)
```

Results for first code run -

```
(Pdb) sess.run(model.cost, feed)
4.9555049
(Pdb) sess.run(model.cost, feed)
4.9548969
```

Expected behaviour, since `DropoutWrapper` uses `random_uniform`.

Results for second code run -

```
(Pdb) sess.run(model.cost, feed)
4.9551616
(Pdb) sess.run(model.cost, feed)
4.9552417
```

Why is this sequence not identical to the first output despite defining an operation and graph seed?

Comment: Do you get same results if you use keep_prob=1.0? There are various things that can introduce non-determinism such as multi-threaded ops, GPU ops (esp ones that use [CUDA atomics](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2732#issuecomment-224661591)), SSE [instructions](http://blog.nag.com/2011/02/wandering-precision.html)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, i get the same results for `keep_prob=1`. I'm using a CPU only TensorFlow

Comment: What if you also set operation level seed? ([docs](https://github.com/petewarden/tensorflow_makefile/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/api_docs/python/functions_and_classes/tf.set_random_seed.md))

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I have set it, like i've described in the question

Comment: weird, maybe worth getting a minimal example of this behavior for a bug report

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov is it necessary to begin the code with `tf.set_default_graph` for deterministic results?

Comment: it should not be necessary, the intention is that things work as documented, and there's no documentation saying that `set_default_graph` is needed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135422/discussion-between-martianwars-and-yaroslav-bulatov).

Comment: `tf.dynamic.rnn` is the culprit. @YaroslavBulatov, do you think this is because `dynamic.rnn` runs iterations in parallel, it has a non deterministic order of calls to `random_uniform()` whenever `keep_prob < 1`?

Comment: `parallel_iterations=1` does work! Do you think this makes sense @YaroslavBulatov?

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov could you write an answer on this? I'm not really sure about `tf.nn.dynamic_rnn` works

Comment: I think it makes sense since you get non-determinism when you run 2 things in parallel. IE, `op1 reads random, op2 reads random, op2 outputs result, op1 outputs result`, vs `op1 reads random, op2 reads random, op1 outputs result, op2 outputs result`. Both orders are possible, but would give different results when `random` is a deterministic sequence

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was already provided in the comments, but no-one has written it explicitly yet, so here it is:

`dynamic_rnn` will internally use `tf.while_loop`, which can actually evaluate multiple iterations in parallel (see documentation on `parallel_iterations`). In practice, if everything inside the loop-body or loop-cond depends on the previous values, it cannot run anything in parallel but there could be computations which don't depend on the previous values. These will be evaluated in parallel. In your case, inside the `DropoutWrapper`, you have at some point sth like this:

```
random_ops.random_uniform(noise_shape, ...)
```

This operation is independent from the previous values of the loop, so it can be calculated in parallel for all time-steps. If you do such parallel execution, it will be non-deterministic which time-frame gets which dropout mask.