# Tensorflow: There is a difference in gradient and loss for the same structure

Tags: python, tensorflow, gradient

With gradient and loss, I experiment with the learning process of a neural network.

I assumed that learning process(loss function value, gradient value) are same if learning conditions(model structure, initialization, batch input stream) of two models are same.

Under the same initialization, I thought that the gradient and loss calculated for each model would be the same, but the result was not.

The code I have run is the most basic learning code, as shown below.

(to constrained the randomness of dropout, I just deactivated the dropout layer)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
#from pprint import pprint
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

batch_size = 128
test_size = 256

def init_weights(shape):
    return tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.01, seed=1))

def model(X, w, w2, w3, w4, w_o, p_keep_conv, p_keep_hidden):

    l1a = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(X, w,                       # l1a shape=(?, 28, 28, 32)
                        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))
    l1 = tf.nn.max_pool(l1a, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],              # l1 shape=(?, 14, 14, 32)
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    #l1 = tf.nn.dropout(l1, p_keep_conv)

    l2a = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(l1, w2,                     # l2a shape=(?, 14, 14, 64)
                        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))
    l2 = tf.nn.max_pool(l2a, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],              # l2 shape=(?, 7, 7, 64)
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    #l2 = tf.nn.dropout(l2, p_keep_conv)

    l3a = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(l2, w3,                     # l3a shape=(?, 7, 7, 128)
                        strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME'))
    l3 = tf.nn.max_pool(l3a, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],              # l3 shape=(?, 4, 4, 128)
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')
    l3 = tf.reshape(l3, [-1, w4.get_shape().as_list()[0]])    # reshape to (?, 2048)
    #l3 = tf.nn.dropout(l3, p_keep_conv)

    l4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(l3, w4))
    #l4 = tf.nn.dropout(l4, p_keep_hidden)

    pyx = tf.matmul(l4, w_o)
    return pyx


mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("MNIST_data/", one_hot=True)
trX, trY, teX, teY = mnist.train.images, mnist.train.labels, mnist.test.images, mnist.test.labels
trX = trX.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)  # 28x28x1 input img
teX = teX.reshape(-1, 28, 28, 1)  # 28x28x1 input img

X0 = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 28, 28, 1], name='input_0')
X1 = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 28, 28, 1], name='input_1')
Y  = tf.placeholder("float", [None, 10])

with tf.variable_scope('00'):
    w0_1 = init_weights([3, 3, 1, 32])       # 3x3x1 conv, 32 outputs
    w0_2 = init_weights([3, 3, 32, 64])     # 3x3x32 conv, 64 outputs
    w0_3 = init_weights([3, 3, 64, 128])    # 3x3x32 conv, 128 outputs
    w0_4 = init_weights([128 * 4 * 4, 625]) # FC 128 * 4 * 4 inputs, 625 outputs
    w0_o = init_weights([625, 10])         # FC 625 inputs, 10 outputs (labels)

with tf.variable_scope('01'):
    w1_1 = init_weights([3, 3, 1, 32])       # 3x3x1 conv, 32 outputs
    w1_2 = init_weights([3, 3, 32, 64])     # 3x3x32 conv, 64 outputs
    w1_3 = init_weights([3, 3, 64, 128])    # 3x3x32 conv, 128 outputs
    w1_4 = init_weights([128 * 4 * 4, 625]) # FC 128 * 4 * 4 inputs, 625 outputs
    w1_o = init_weights([625, 10])         # FC 625 inputs, 10 outputs (labels)


p_keep_conv = tf.placeholder("float")
p_keep_hidden = tf.placeholder("float")

py_x0 = model(X0, w0_1, w0_2, w0_3, w0_4, w0_o, p_keep_conv, p_keep_hidden)
py_x1 = model(X1, w1_1, w1_2, w1_3, w1_4, w1_o, p_keep_conv, p_keep_hidden)



cost0 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=py_x0, labels=Y))
cost1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=py_x1, labels=Y))



model_0_vars = [tensor for tensor in tf.trainable_variables() if '00/' in tensor.name]
model_1_vars = [tensor for tensor in tf.trainable_variables() if '01/' in tensor.name]

#pprint(model_0_vars)
#pprint(model_1_vars)


train_op_model_0_grad = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001, 0.9).compute_gradients(cost0, var_list = model_0_vars)
train_op_model_0_apply= tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001, 0.9).apply_gradients(train_op_model_0_grad)


train_op_model_1_grad = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001, 0.9).compute_gradients(cost1, var_list = model_1_vars)
train_op_model_1_apply= tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001, 0.9).apply_gradients(train_op_model_1_grad)


predict_op_0 = tf.argmax(py_x0, 1)
predict_op_1 = tf.argmax(py_x1, 1)



# Launch the graph in a session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # you need to initialize all variables
    tf.initialize_all_variables().run()



    step = 0
    for i in range(2):
        #check_weight_tmp = sess.run([model_0_vars, model_1_vars])
        #check_weight.append(check_weight_tmp)

        training_batch = zip(range(0, len(trX), batch_size),
                             range(batch_size, len(trX)+1, batch_size))


        for start, end in training_batch:
            step +=1

            grad0, grad1 = \
            sess.run([train_op_model_0_grad, train_op_model_1_grad], 
                     feed_dict={X0: trX[start:end], X1: trX[start:end], Y: trY[start:end],
                                p_keep_conv: 0.8, p_keep_hidden: 0.5})


            cost0_r, cost1_r = \
            sess.run([cost0, cost1], 
                     feed_dict={X0: trX[start:end], X1: trX[start:end], Y: trY[start:end],
                                p_keep_conv: 0.8, p_keep_hidden: 0.5})

            sess.run([train_op_model_0_apply, train_op_model_1_apply],
                      feed_dict={X0: trX[start:end], X1: trX[start:end], Y: trY[start:end],
                                 p_keep_conv: 0.8, p_keep_hidden: 0.5})


            print("STEP: {0:5d}, {1:3.6f}, {2:3.6f}, {3:3.6f}".format(step, cost0_r, cost1_r, cost0_r - cost1_r))



        #test_indices = np.arange(len(teX)) # Get A Test Batch
        #np.random.shuffle(test_indices)
        #test_indices = test_indices[0:test_size]

        #print(i, np.mean(np.argmax(teY[test_indices], axis=1) ==
        #                 sess.run(predict_op_0,
        #                          feed_dict={X: teX[test_indices],
        #                                     Y: teY[test_indices],
        #                                     p_keep_conv: 1.0,
        #                                     p_keep_hidden: 1.0})))
```

There is a noticeable difference in loss from the 200th epoch.

I think I have missed it, but I can't figure it out even I spend a long time to look at it.

I would appreciate if you could let me know what I am missing.

Comment: Without looking too closely at your code, have you tried resetting the random generator to the seed after one model has been fully trained?
See [`tf.set_random_seed()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed) for more details.

Comment: As far as I know,

the 'seed' in the tf.random_normal(shape, stddev=0.01, seed=1) of uploaded code 

is actually force random_normal generator to generate the same sequence,

and this is exactly same as using tf.set_random_seed("seed").

However, I will try tf.set_random_seed() anyway, to check whether there is difference between tf.random_seed() and the specific random values generator from a normal distribution.

Comment: I tried tf.set_random_seed() as you mentioned, instead of fixing seed of random generator, but result is same. Still, I can't figure out the why each gradient and loss for two models are different, not identical.

Comment: Yes, the seed in your `random_normal` has been noted, too, but you never know where TensorFlow does utilize randomness elsewhere. Did you also compare the values of the first model across different runs? Are they the same? Then it is indeed an issue of *where* you set the random_seed

Comment: I found some questions that related to this issues, and it seems that they called stable result issues. 
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156296/dropoutwrapper-being-non-deterministic-across-runs>
<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36288235/how-to-get-stable-results-with-tensorflow-setting-random-seed>          


Someone pointed out that parallel computation can cause the unstable result due to its independency from the previous values of the loop.
(I didn't fully understand what this means, but may be computing gradients of mini-batch cause the problem?)

Comment: continue to above comments...

Even tough weights of two models are changed whenver they excuted, but I also confirmed that these two model started with identical weights value in each simulation, so I think gradients and loss of these two models should be identical. (even though this pair is not identical to that of the next or previous simulation)

I still wonder what cause this difference, and what randomness should I regulate to get stable result.

Answer (score 1):

This difference in loss can happen because of overfitting, when the program has already trained itself to recognise the data, and is now over-generalises input. I experienced it myself while training an audio tool.